# Вырезать поддомен из URL

Tags: php

Есть ссылка:
http://www.site.com

Подскажите пожалуйста как вырезать поддомен из данного адрес.

Тоесть любая ссылка http://(*).site.com, превращалась в site.com

http://site.com           = site.com
http://blocg.site.com     = site.com
http://forum.site.com     = site.com
http://www.site.com       = site.com

Answer (score 1):

IMHO без регулярок быстрей будет:

```
 function get_subdomain($url) {
     $segments = parse_url($url);
     return current(explode('.', $segments['host'], 2));
 }

echo get_subdomain('http://blocg.site.com'); //blocg
```

http://ideone.com/PgnAeL